# PHP How to add HTML to another HTML at a specific point?

Tags: php

I have this link like so:

```
$link = '<a href="#" title="box">do something</a>';
```

Now I need to add html to the end of the text within the anchor tag so it ends up like this:

```
$link = '<a href="#" title="box">do something<i class="arrow"></i></a>';
```

I have researched around and my conclusion is that I probably have to use regular expression but I don't know where to start.  I know this can be done easily via JS but I need it done in PHP.

Any ideas?

Comment: might want to look into PHP DOM manipulation

Comment: isn't it faster to write exactly what you wrote in the second example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)-

```
$link = '<a href="#" title="box">do something</a>';
$link = str_replace("</a>", '<i class="arrow"></i></a>', $link);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using substrings and concatenation:

```
$link = '<a href="#" title="box">do something</a>';
$addition = '<i class="arrow"></i>';

$formatted_str = substr($link, 0, strlen($link) - 4) . $addition . substr($link, strlen($link) - 4);

echo $formatted_str;
```